# How to delete the rest of each line after a certain pattern or a string in a file?

Tags: text-processing, sed

Suppose I have a list of URLs in a text file:

```
google.com/funny
unix.stackexchange.com/questions
isuckatunix.com/ireallydo
```

I want to delete everything that comes after '.com'.

Expected Results:

```
google.com
unix.stackexchange.com
isuckatunix.com
```

I tried

```
sed 's/.com*//' file.txt
```

but it deleted `.com` as well.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for which you want to search for `.com` only instead of removing everything after and including the first `/` character? What if you had a URL like `en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu` in your list?

Comment: @ByteCommander The answer below replaces doesn't remove. I am in need of removing everything after a pattern but keeping the pattern.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To explicitly delete everything that comes after ".com", just tweak your existing sed solution to replace ".com(anything)" with ".com":

```
sed 's/\.com.*/.com/' file.txt
```

I tweaked your regex to escape the first period; otherwise it would have matched something like "thisiscommon.com/something".

Note that you may want to further anchor the ".com" pattern with a trailing forward-slash so that you don't accidentally trim something like "sub.com.domain.com/foo":

```
sed 's/\.com\/.*/.com/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use [`awk`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gawk.1.html)'s field separator (`-F`) following way:

```
$ cat file
google.com/funny
unix.stackexchange.com/questions
isuckatunix.com/ireallydo
```

```
$ <file awk -F '\\.com' '{print $1".com"}'
google.com
unix.stackexchange.com
isuckatunix.com
```

Explanation:

```
NAME
       awk - pattern scanning and processing language


-F fs
       --field-separator fs
              Use fs for the input field separator (the value of the FS predefined variable).
```

As you want to delete every things after `.com`, `-F '\\.com'` separates line with `.com` and `print $1` gives output only the part before `.com`. So, `$1".com"` adds `.com` and gives you expected output.

Comment: [Why not just `/` as FS](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257515/68757) and take the first field?

Comment: @heemayl http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257514/how-to-delete-everything-after-a-certain-pattern-or-a-string-in-a-file#comment445407_257515

Answer (score 6):

**The best tool for non-interactive in-place file editing is `ex`.**

```
ex -sc '%s/\(\.com\).*/\1/ | x' file.txt
```

If you've used `vi` and if you've ever typed a command that begins with a colon `:` you've used an ex command.  Of course many of the more advanced or "fancy" commands you can execute this way are Vim extensions (e.g. `:bufdo`) and are not defined in the [POSIX specifications for `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html), but those specifications allow for a truly astonishing degree of power and flexibility in non-visual text editing (whether interactive or automated).

The command above has several parts.

`-s` enables silent mode to prepare `ex` for batch use.  (Suppress output messages et. al.)

`-c` specifies the command to execute once the file (`file.txt`, in this case) is opened in a buffer.

`%` is an address specifier equivalent to `1,$`—it means that the following command is applied to all lines of the buffer.

`s` is the substitute command that you are likely familiar with already.  It is commonly used in `vi` and has essentially identical features to the [`s` command of `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03), though some of the advanced regex features may vary by implementation.  In this case from ".com" to the end of the line is replaced with just ".com".

The vertical bar separates sequential commands to be executed.  In many (most) `ex` implementations you can also use an additional `-c` option, like so:

```
ex -sc '%s/\(\.com\).*/\1/' -c x file.txt
```

However, this is not required by POSIX.

The `x` command exits, after writing any changes to the file.  Unlike `wq` which means "write and quit", `x` only writes to the file if the buffer has been edited.  Thus if your file is unaltered, the timestamp will be preserved.

Comment: It doesnt edit in-place. At least, it doesnt any more than Gnu `sed`'s bogus -i does. It reads/writes to on-disk buffers. See for yourself w/ `ex -r` and the `preserve` command.

Comment: @mikeserv What's the `preserve` command?

Answer (score 3):

Very quick, simple and dirty python way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
with open( sys.argv[1]  ) as file:
    for line in file:
        print line.split("/")[0]
```

Sample run

```
skolodya@ubuntu:$ chmod +x removeStrings.py                                   

skolodya@ubuntu:$ ./removeStrings.py strings.txt                              
google.com
unix.stackexchange.com
isuckatunix.com


skolodya@ubuntu:$ cat strings.txt                                             
google.com/funny
unix.stackexchange.com/questions
isuckatunix.com/ireallydo
```

Comment: It works, but it does not care about `.com`, it just removes everything starting with the first `/` in the line. (which is in my opinion even the better approach!)

Comment: @ByteCommander exactly right ! If domain name is `.net`, in other approaches the part that comes after domain and extension wouldn't get deleted, so it's safer to use `/` as separator.

Answer (score -2):

- Delete everything after a string

  ```shell
  sed 's/\.com.*/.com/'
  ```

  example:

  ```shell
  sed 's/\.com.*/.com/' filename >> filename
  ```
- Delete everything before a certain word

  ```shell
  sed 's/^.*can/can/' filename >> filename
  ```

Comment: The basic solution in this answer duplicates another answer. You added some examples, but they are flawed: appending to `filename` while processing `filename` will cause the file to grow and grow until "no space left"; unless `filename` is small enough, so`sed` reads the whole of it in one chunk, but you should never count on it. This is why I vote down.